# Hibernate - saveAndFlush with trigger in postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using SpringBoot, Hibernate and Postgres
In Postgres DB I have before INSERT trigger,which inserts some values to some columns depending on other entries in this table.

I want to get those values in my app after saving this entity, modify them and update this entity with modified values

I am able to get them in saveAndFlush method result, but after their modification and saving them again, they are not stored in DB (as if I didn't make any modification). Below is code

```
ExampleEntity initiallySavedEntity = entityRepository.saveAndFlush(exampleEntity);
initiallySavedEntity.setPropertyPopulatedByTrigger("blablabla");
entityRepository.save(initiallySavedEntity);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@Generated` annotation is what you are looking for in this case: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-Generated